# Why am I getting an "undefined column error"

Tags: r, spatial

I am getting this error when I run my script.

Script

---

`# Analyze another data set with row / col data using SpATS
library(plantbreeding)    # load library

data(dataset)
head (dataset)
str(dataset)

dataset$genotypes<-as.factor(dataset$genotypes)

m1 <- SpATS(response = "yield", spatial = ~ SAP(columns, rows), genotype = "genotypes", data = dataset)
plot(m1, all.in.one = TRUE)  # see all plots in a common plot`

---

Dataset is arranged as follows.

[image]

Variables are as follows.
`> str(dataset) tibble [87 x 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame) $ genotypes: Factor w/ 87 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 66 51 64 62 77 2 86 69 21 74 ... $ Columns  : num [1:87] 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 ... $ Rows     : num [1:87] 55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73 ... $ yield    : num [1:87] 235 NA 152 119 146 ...`

---

Error that I am getting.
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.terms) : undefined columns selected

I have tried taking the quotes of variables but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is this somehow related to the `spatstat` package or did you use that tag in error?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  I copied the error from comments from R.  The script works fine for replicated analysis but will not work for single replication experiments.  I am looking to spatially adjust large single replication experiments.

Comment: My question is whether you are using the `spatstat` package in your analysis at all? It doesn't seem so to me, but the tag `spatstat` here on Stackoverflow is supposed to only be used for questions about the `spatstat` package. Maybe you want to use the tags `r` and `spatial` instead?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I will try those tags.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg